# One to many relationships using Web service & local database MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently working on an assignment at university from which I unfortunatly lost some code to not long ago.
In particular it is where I have specific products display to a specific store, the code I have is not working
at all for me now, help would be appreciated

I have a web service and a local database in place from which the web service brings in the product information
and the local information has the store data and the store grade data.

Here is the code that I have in place for it to display on the details view page.

```
@model Part1MVC.ViewModels.GradeProductVM

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>
<fieldset><legend>GradeProductVM</legend>
<div class="display-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gradeid)</div>
<div class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Gradeid)</div>
<div class="display-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GradeName)</div>
<div class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.GradeName)</div>
</fieldset>

<div>There are @Model.Products.Count products</div>
@foreach (var prod in Model.Products) { <div>@prod.ProductName</div>}
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.Gradeid }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")</p>
```

// This is the code for service1.cs to get grades product

```
    public List<PhysicalProduct> GetProductsForGrade(int gradeid){
        var list = new List<PhysicalProduct>();
        try {
            using (var db = new ProductsEntities()) {
                var q = from prod in db.PhysicalProducts
                        join pg in db.ProductToGrades on prod.ProductId equals pg.ProductId
                        where pg.StoreGradeId == gradeid
                        select prod;
                return q.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
        return list;
    }
```

////This is the controller code

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id){
        Grade grade = db.Grade.SingleOrDefault(x => x.GradeId == id);
        //var products = ServiceLayer.GetProducts();
        var products = ServiceLayer.GetProductsForGrade(id);
        var vm = new ViewModels.GradeProductVM(id, grade.Description, products);
        return View(vm);
    }
```

//This is the View model Code

```
public class GradeProductVM {
    public int Gradeid { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }
    public List<PhysicalProduct> Products { get; set; }

    public GradeProductVM() {

    }
    public GradeProductVM(int gradeid, string name, List<PhysicalProduct> prods){
        Gradeid = gradeid;
        GradeName = name;
        Products = prods;

    }
}
```

I can get all the products that are currently in the database to display to every store but not specific products to specific stores.

Thanks

Comment: In your code does a "store" equate to a grade?

Answer (score 0):

Please post the database table structure, seems the query join may be wrong. 
Rest seems correct!